# Remove a foreign key column using a Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am simply trying to remove a foreign key column from a table. I have this in migration:

```
def change
  remove_column :addresses, :contact_id
end
```

However, I get the following error:

> Mysql2::Error: Cannot drop index 'index_addresses_on_contact_id':
>   needed in a foreign key constraint: ALTER TABLE `addresses` DROP
>   `contact_id`

So how do I remove this foreign key constraint in the Rails migration too?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try...

```
def change
  remove_reference :addresses, :contact, index: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Comment: Yes I tried this but now I realized when I tried it, I had :contacts rather than :contact. When I have addresses plural and contact singular, it works.